# Using Transactions in Django for Temporary Data Manipulation: Is Rollback a Viable Strategy?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, rollback

I am currently working on a Django application with a PostgreSQL database. I need to perform a specific computation that involves temporarily removing some rows from a database table, processing some logic, and then restoring the original state of the data.

I understand that typically, transactions are used to ensure data integrity by only committing all changes if every step is successful, and rolling back changes if an error occurs. However, in this case, I intend to always rollback the transaction after my computation is complete, effectively using the transaction as a "sandbox" for temporary changes.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good/possible practice to use transactions in this way, where a rollback is
   not contingent on an error but is instead a guaranteed part of the
   flow?
2. Could this approach have any negative impacts on database performance or integrity, considering that it will be executed frequently?
3. Is there any other possible approach?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on this matter. If additional details are required, please let me know, and I will provide them.

Thank you in advance!